# What is the correct way to respond to peripheralManager:didReceiveWriteRequests?

Tags: core-bluetooth

What is the correct way to respond to `peripheralManager:didReceiveWriteRequests:`?

The header documentation states that:

"For every invocation of this method `respondToRequestWithResult` should be called exactly once."

In `didReceiveWriteRequests` multiple write requests are passed in using an `NSArray`.

If all write requests are succcessfully handled, do we just arbitrarily select a request from the list and use it as the argument for `respondToRequestWithResult` since the `respondToRequestWithResult` method only takes a single `CBATTRequest` argument and not a list of `CBATTRequest`s which comes with `didReceiveWriteRequests`?

I expected a symmetrical respond method taking a list of requests as an argument.

Answer (score 5):

From Apple documentation: [Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/PerformingCommonPeripheralRoleTasks/PerformingCommonPeripheralRoleTasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013257-CH4-SW1)

Handling write requests from a connected central is also straightforward. When a connected central sends a request to write the value of one or more of your characteristics, the peripheral manager calls the peripheralManager:didReceiveWriteRequests: method of its delegate object. This time, the delegate method delivers the requests to you in the form of an array containing one or more CBATTRequest objects, each representing a write request. After you have ensured that a write request can be fulfilled, you can write the characteristic’s value, like this:

```
myCharacteristic.value = request.value;
```

Although the above example does not demonstrate this, be sure to take into account the request’s offset property when writing the value of your characteristic.

Just as you respond to a read request, call the respondToRequest:withResult: method exactly once each time the peripheralManager:didReceiveWriteRequests: delegate method is called. That said, the first parameter of the respondToRequest:withResult: method expects a single CBATTRequest object, even though you may have received an array containing more than one of them from the peripheralManager:didReceiveWriteRequests: delegate method. You should pass in the first request of the array, like this:

```
[myPeripheralManager respondToRequest:[requests objectAtIndex:0]

    withResult:CBATTErrorSuccess];
```

Comment: super confusing that you pass in the first request when you have a set of them, is there any reason for this?